# Kendo Scheduler Datasource for multiple input field

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

In following example - http://dojo.telerik.com/IqIYI/5 - I am trying to understand how the data should be saved in my DB (and hence fed to the scheduler).

This is my custom edit template.

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">    <h3>Edit meeting</h3>    <p>
       <label>Title: <input name="title" /></label>    </p>    <p>
       <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="start" /></label>    </p>    <p>
       <label>End: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="end" /></label>    </p>    <div class="k-edit-label">
        <label for="Contact">Contact</label>
    </div>
    <div data-container-for="Contact" class="k-edit-field">
        <select id="Contact" multiple="multiple" name="Contact"
            data-role="multiselect"
            data-bind="value:Contact"
            data-source='[
                { "text": "Person1", "value": 1 },
                { "text": "Person2", "value": 2 },
                { "text": "Person3", "value": 3 }
            ]'
            data-text-field="text"
            data-value-field="value"
            data-value-primitive="true"
            ></select>
    </div> </script>
```

And my datasource for the only event (seen on the right in the example) is following:

```
dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview",
      contact: "[1, 2]"
    }
  ]
```

..The start, end date and the title fill the popup properly (when double clicking the "Interview" event on the right to show its contents).
However the Contact field does not fill.
I tried the following to no avail, does anyone have a clue?

```
contact: [1,2]
contact: {1,2}
contact: [{1,2}]
contact: [{value:1, value:2}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name and data-bind in your template aren't correct (lowercase "c"); you need:

```
<div data-container-for="Contact" class="k-edit-field">
    <select id="Contact" multiple="multiple" name="contact"
        data-role="multiselect"
        data-bind="value:contact"
        data-source='[
            { "text": "Person1", "value": 1 },
            { "text": "Person2", "value": 2 },
            { "text": "Person3", "value": 3 }
        ]'
        data-text-field="text"
        data-value-field="value"
        data-value-primitive="true"
        ></select>
</div>
```

Then this value will work:

```
contact: [1,2]
```

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/UYIzi))